# What to do if you can't understand a part of a solution to math problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, advice, learning

What to do if you don't understand a part of a solution? Beside asking. What are the common strategies?

Comment: Highlight the specific part of the solution which leads to the break in understanding that you're experiencing, and try to ask someone more experienced.

Comment: There are a few thing you can do. You could ask your teacher. You could Google for more complete solutions. Or you could ask for clarification here on MSE, but there are a few guidelines you'll need to follow: 1) post the question and solution exactly as they're written 2) tell us where it comes from or why it matters and 3) articulate exactly which part of the solution you didn't understand

Comment: You need to understand the broader purpose that that part of the solution serves. Get a broad picture of the solution first - understand what needs to be shown and what the general strategy is. Try to understand what you'd be missing if you cut out the part of the solution that you don't understand. If none of that works, look for other references or similar solutions that you can compare to.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.